# How to download Magento 1 version?

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, download

I just want to check whether we can download Magento 1 in anyway. In Magento download page, I cannot see an option to download the Magento 1. I just want to download this to test how migration works.

https://adobe.ly/3DzYE79

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Magento 1 from below link all the versions available there.

https://blog.magestore.com/magento-download/

Answer (score 1):

You can dowload Magento 1 from https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror.